# Comparison of the text retrieved from getAttribute with the variable

Tags: javascript

why retrieve the text with the getAttribute method returns a different string than the same text assigned to the variable ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div name="other" txt="text\ttest\nparse\tnew\nline">test</div>
  </body>
</html>

var d1 = document.querySelector("[name=other]");
var text = d1.getAttribute("txt");

var text2 = "text\ttest\nparse\tnew\nline";
console.log(text.localeCompare(text2));
console.log(text);
console.log(text2);
```

text\ttest\nparse\tnew\nline != text\ttest\nparse\tnew\nline

[https://jsfiddle.net/qva3ubjt/](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: One string, `text2`, is escaped with the backslashes, the other is interpreted literally -- as in, the backslashes are interpreted to be back slashes.

Comment: Did you expect `\n` in the attribute to become a new line?

Comment: Just a word of warning: neither `name` or `txt` are valid HTML attributes on `div`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have not preserved the `escape characters` once you have fetched the value from the `getAttribute` method.

Try something like this :

```
var d1 = document.querySelector("[name=other]");
var text = d1.getAttribute("txt");

var text2 = "text\ttest\nparse\tnew\nline";
console.log(text.localeCompare(escape(text2)));


function escape(s) {
    return ('' + s) /* Forces the conversion to string. */
        .replace(/\\/g, '\\\\') /* This MUST be the 1st replacement. */
        .replace(/\t/g, '\\t') /* These 2 replacements protect whitespaces. */
        .replace(/\n/g, '\\n')
        .replace(/\u00A0/g, '\\u00A0') /* Useful but not absolutely necessary. */
        .replace(/&/g, '\\x26') /* These 5 replacements protect from HTML/XML. */
        .replace(/'/g, '\\x27')
        .replace(/"/g, '\\x22')
        .replace(/</g, '\\x3C')
        .replace(/>/g, '\\x3E')
        ;
}
```

Comment: You should avoid `alert()` for debugging, use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: @PeterKrebs: noted. thanks for the same

Comment: Sure no problemYou can make the code run directly in StackOverflow with the `<>` button by the way. You would have to provide some minimal HTML to run the selectors on but it's very easy to see that way if your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could just define the html attributes with *actual* tab and newline characters:

```js
var d1 = document.querySelector(".other");
var text = d1.dataset.txt;

var text2 = "text\ttest\nparse\tnew\nline";
console.log(text);
console.log(text2);
console.log(`The strings ${text.localeCompare(text2)?"differ":"are the same"}.`);
```

```html
<div class="other" data-txt="text   test
parse   new
line">test</div>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work in the snippet saved here. While running the script in the editing mode the comparison results in both strings being the same, but when saved, an extra space seems to creep in somewhere.